# Fragment replaced still catch backPressed

Tags: android, replace, android-fragments, transactions, back-button

I'm using one Activity which contains one Fragment at a time. I use support.v4.
The "onBackPressed" of Activity and Fragment is override, so I can't use the original back button, I have to override it myself.

So I'm in fragment A, I go to fragment B. Fragment B displays a list of results, and when I pick a line, it goes to Fragment C.
When I'm on C and I press back button, I want to go back on B with the results displayed. And if I press back button again, I'll go to A.
It looks simple.

I manage the come back from C to B. The thing is when I hit the back button on B, it calls Fragment C backPressed.

A -> B -> C -> B (display B but BackButton don't work anymore).

Some code : 
backPressed in Fragment C

```
public void backPressed() {

FragmentTransaction transaction = ((FragmentActivity)m_context).getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
transaction.replace(R.id.mainactivity_fragmentcontainer,((FragmentActivity)m_context).getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("customtag"), "customtag");
transaction.commitAllowingStateLoss();

}
```

Fragment B has the tag "customtag".

When I replace B by C:

```
FragmentC newFrag = new FragmentC(m_context);FragmentTransaction transac = ((FragmentActivity)m_context).getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
((FragmentContainerActivity)m_context).setCurrentFragment(newFrag);
transac.replace(R.id.mainactivity_fragmentcontainer, newFrag);
transac.addToBackStack(null);
transac.commitAllowingStateLoss();
```

Any idea why the fragmentC which is replaced (the display changes and I can see fragment B) still get the back button action?

Thanks for your help.

**EDIT**
Code of backPressed in Fragment B (however the application never goes there when it comes from Fragment C).

```
@Override
public void backPressed() {
    Log.e("FragmentB", "backPressed");
    //I have 2 views in FragB. If View2 is visible, I make it gone and display View1
    if(mainView.findViewById(R.id.view2).getVisibility()==View.VISIBLE){
        displayView1();
    }else{
        if(fromFragmentX){
            FragmentX fragX = new FragmentX(ctx);
            FragmentTransaction transac = ((FragmentActivity)ctx).getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            ((FragmentContainerActivity)ctx).setCurrentFragment(fragX);
            transac.replace(R.id.mainactivity_fragmentcontainer, fragX);
            transac.commitAllowingStateLoss();
        }else{
            super.backPressed();
        }
    }
}
```

**SECOND EDIT**

I realize I forgot to precise something.
When I'm replacing fragment B by fragment C, I'm doing it in the ArrayAdapter of the ListView in Fragment B, but it shouldn't change anything.

Anyway, I tried something different somewhere else in the app.
In FragmentU, I replace FragmentU by Fragment C (always the same), and I'm setting an attribute in  Fragment C which is :

```
private CustomFragment fragmentFrom;
```

So on backPressed in FragmentC, in case I'm from Fragment U, I call :

```
FragmentTransaction transaction = ((FragmentActivity)ctx).getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
transaction.replace(R.id.mainactivity_fragmentcontainer, fragmentFrom);
transaction.commitAllowingStateLoss();
```

And I still got the same problem. When coming back from Fragment C, the Fragment U is displayed, and works well, but the back button call FragmentC.backPressed.

Comment: Just to have a clear picture... backPressed() does not exist in Fragment class. Did you implement it?

Comment: You helped me a lot!
The "backPressed" in the fragment call the "OnBackPressed" from the main Activity. In the onBackPressed, there is this call :
currentFrag.backPressed();
So I just have a problem with the currentFrag which is not well set.
Thanks a lot fasteque.